# what is this component called which can be kept in foreground in html code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider

i have question about the comonent which is in th middle of the picture whcich has 3 big buttons and the central button is in foreground and the other two are in the background.
I have to put this component in my project but i dont know what this component is called . thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUNPP.png)

Comment: If you have to swipe over to the background layers, the only name I can give it is "overcomplicated"...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you mean to say it cannot be done or there is no component like this .

Comment: as we have carousel ,slider etc ...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol sir ?

Comment: It's a carousel - there are a number of ways of styling them and this is one. I've also seen it referred to as "CoverFlow" (or "Cover Flow") styling (or as a "CoverFlow").